# encrypt file with embedded spaces

Tags: shell

I have the following files in a directory and run the following command:

gpg --yes --encrypt-files -r MyPublicKey $( ls -1A | egrep -v '.dat')

myfile1.dat
myfile1.txt
myfile2.dat
myfile2.txt
myfile3.dat
myfile3.txt
myfile4.dat
myfile4.txt
  . my file . txt
.myfile.txt

The gpg command is having a problem with a file called \.\my\file.\txt\
The backslashes represent spaces.

If I redo the command as follows the \.\my\file.\txt\ file with embedded spaces get encrypted.

gpg --yes --encrypt-files -r  MyPublicKey *

Any ideas how to make the command gpg --yes --encrypt-files -r MyPublicKey $( ls -1A | egrep -v '.dat') work and encrypt the file with embedded spaces ?

gpg --yes --encrypt-files -r MyPublicKey $( ls -1A | egrep -v '.dat')

myfile1.dat
myfile1.txt
myfile2.dat
myfile2.txt
myfile3.dat
myfile3.txt
myfile4.dat
myfile4.txt
  . my file . txt
.myfile.txt

Comment: I also set the variable from the default value to IFS=   thinking that it might make a difference but it did not

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Bash, you can use an extglob instead to easily and safely get all filenames that don't match a pattern:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
gpg --yes --encrypt-files -r MyPublicKey !(*.dat)
```

Otherwise, you can use `find`:

```
#!/bin/sh
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 ! -name '*.dat' \
    -exec gpg --yes --encrypt-files -r MyPublicKey {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
gpg --yes --encrypt-files -r MyPublicKey "$( ls -1A | egrep -v '.dat')"
```

(see the quotes added around the substitution).

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked for me but will try your suggestions.

ls -1A | egrep -v '.dat$' |  egrep -v '.gpg$' | while IFS= read -r line; do gpg --yes --encrypt -r MyPublicKey "$line"; done